# Azure Point-to-Site VPN Client: How to configure the Azure Private DNS Resolver IP?

Tags: azure, azure-vpn, azure-private-dns

I connected to the Azure Network using the Azure Point-to-Site VPN Client. Additionally, I configured the Azure Private DNS Resolver, and I was able to resolve the Private Endpoint by specifying the IP address of the Azure Private DNS Resolver.

> C:\>nslookup kv-prod-centralus-d4.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net 10.0.0.36
>
> Server: UnKnown
>
> Address:  10.0.0.36
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>
> Name:  kv-prod-centralus-d4.privatelink.vaultcore.azure.net
>
> Address: 10.1.3.5

I don't want to specify the IP address of the Azure Private DNS Resolver in the nslookup command.

According to my understanding, Azure Point-to-Site VPN Client Configuration should include the IP address of the Azure Private DNS Resolver.

I see the following configuration file part of the VPN zip file

[image]

However, I'm not sure how to update the Azure Point-to-Site VPN Client configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results*

> I have created the virtual network and VPN gateway
> configured the point to site vpn and downloaded the vpn certificate

[image]

> Below is my configuration xml file

[image]

*I have downloaded the VPN client using this Reference [URL](https://install.appcenter.ms/users/user-microsoft/apps/azure-vpn-client-1/distribution_groups/publicgroup/releases/9)*

> I have imported the Client configuration file that will be download from the VPN gateway

[image]

> After importing the file given the filename saved that file

[image]

> Connect the VPN by clicking the Connect button

[image]

> We can also connect the by clicking the VPN settings

[image]

> And search for the network we want to connect and click on connect

[image]

> *For related information check this reference [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/openvpn-azure-ad-client)*

Comment: How the URL https://install.appcenter.ms/users/user-microsoft/apps/azure-vpn-client-1/distribution_groups/publicgroup/releases/9 different from downloading the VPN agent from Virtual Gateway?